# Is it worth the trouble to avoid using the SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue method?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, parameter-passing

[Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345323/addwithvalue-without-dbtype-causing-queries-to-run-slowly) [articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221041441/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Rhames/archive/2008/10/29/why-you-should-always-specify-the-sqldbtype-for-an-ado.net.aspx) tells you that you should avoid using AddWithValue method because it can lead to poor execution plans and performance. Should I go through my DAL and change all parameters to specify the SqlDbType? Is it worth the loss in maintainability? (If I change a column-type from varchar(50) to varchar(100) I would need to change all the places it is used.)

Comment: For new code, I would add parameters with SqlDbType specified. For old code, when I touch it for other reasons, I would change it so that SqlDbType is specified for each parameter. Eventually they'll get cleaned up. In my opinion performance will be better and DB admin will be much happier, at least that's my experience with DB admin. How often do you change your column type? If you do it often, you're not doing it right. If you don't do it often, there is no loss in maintainability.

Comment: For the specific aspect of `AddWithValue` inferring `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` this can be mitigated by database collation. If you are using a SQL collation any index on a `varchar` column will be rendered unusable by this data type mismatch. In  Windows collations it can often still convert these to a seek. Still not optimal but useful. Unfortunately `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is still the default in a lot of cases