# Issue with conducting SQL statement within ASP.Net C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

doubles quotes dont work so you have to type 'some value' to actually do variable comparisons when doing direct execution of SQL statements.

**Problem is that now when I execute the SQL statement from ASP.NET code I dont seem to be getting any readings**...I am not even getting errors :S....

I HAVE tried executing the SQL statement on its own, and it does work.

```
public static string testExi(string localIncidentNum)
        {

            try
            {
                string query = "SELECT TOP 1 UniqueColID From DBNAME WHERE LocalIncidentNum = @localIncidentNum ORDER BY [version] DESC";

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@localIncidentNum", localIncidentNum);

                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                adp.Fill(dt);
                connection.Close();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Dispose();

                if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                    string UniqueColID = dt.Rows[0]["UniqueColID"].ToString();
                    return UniqueColID;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }


                string some = dt.Rows[0]["UniqueColID"].ToString();
                return some;
            }


            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Global.tmpmsg = " Updating follow up was not successful. " + err.ToString();
                return null;
            }


        }
```

**If I hardcode an incident value in the SELECT statement it works but if I hardcode the incident value in .addwithvalue, it doesn't work.**

```
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@localIncidentNum", "12-023696");
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `using` for your SqlConnection object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I (for some reason) needed to put the full path of the table before the table name in sql code when executing it from C sharp file:

```
SELECT TOP 2 [DB name].[dbo]. [table name]
```

Comment: You shouldn't mark your own answer as the best answer because you have totally missed the point (you found a work around, not the answer). The reason you have to fully qualify the table name is because you haven't correctly specified the database/catalogue in your connection string. You've connected to the SQL instance but not to the actual database.

Answer (score 5):

Double check your sql statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 UniqueColID From WHERE LocalIncidentNum = @localIncidentNum ORDER BY [version] DESC
```

`From Where`?

**Edit**
In observance of your change, best to always be as accurate as possible when describing your problem.  Leaving out something like the table name of a sql statement is very misleading.

Comment: Sorry, that is present in my actual code but due to confidentiality i had to erase something and the table name I accidently erased in here when pasting the code but that isnt the issue

Comment: What data type is LocalIncidentNum?

Comment: And you've stepped through your code to ensure that you are actually dealing with a valid localIncidentNum, correct?  In other words, check to ensure it isn't null or empty.  Also, ensure that the connection string that you are using points to the same database where you have tested the sql statement.

Comment: And this works if you run it against your database manually?  `SELECT TOP 1 UniqueColID From DBNAME WHERE LocalIncidentNum = '12-023696'`.  Just FYI, you don't need to add the Order By clause if you are only selecting 1 row.  Also, you have confirmed that your DataTable has no records in it - you mention that you seem to be getting no readings.  Be specific, how do you know you aren't getting any readings?  is it because you aren't getting the expected return value from the function or you know for a fact that DataTable is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a datatype to your command parameter.  I believe that you are not getting anything because it may be timing out on the command.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@localIncidentNum", localIncidentNum);
command.Parameters[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
```

I found a similar problem here, also using Varchar:

[AddWithValue without DBType causing queries to run slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345323/addwithvalue-without-dbtype-causing-queries-to-run-slowly)