# How to insert a unicode character in SQL Server using Inline Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I am using inline query in asp.net but problem is i dont now how to use N suffix properly pls guide....

```
  cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into newsactivity VALUES(@newstitle, @newsdetails ,@dated,@type)",cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newstitle",txtnewstitle.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsdetails",N'txtnewsdetails.Text');
```

Comment: When you are using parameters then setting `SqlDbType` to `NVarChar` should be good enough

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to. .NET strings are already unicode. N is just tells Query Analyzer that the string literal after the *N* is Unicode.

e.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsdetails","मैं stackoverflow प्यार है");
```

Just make sure that the field `newsdetails` in your `newsactivity` table is `NVARCHAR(..)`

**Edit**
That's strange. Possibly AddWithValue hasn't inferred the type of the parameter correctly. You can specify it explicitly:

```
SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsdetails",txtnewsdetails.Text);
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

Another good reason to specify the type and length explicitly is if you are using the parameter in a WHERE clause filter. See [AddWithValue without DBType causing queries to run slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345323/addwithvalue-without-dbtype-causing-queries-to-run-slowly)

Comment: its nvarchar already ... and its a freetextbox but after saving it displays ????? chars....how ever sql server accepts unicode when i insert it directly in sql server

Answer (score 4):

It should be enough to say

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newsdetails", txtnewsdetails.Text);
```

EDIT: Should that fail, then this should work:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newsdetails", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1024).Value = txtnewsdetails.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SqlDbType.NVarChar` in your parameter.